# Visual Studio 2017/2019 Drivers Development

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

In order to develop drivers (both kernel-mode drivers and user-mode drivers) we need to have in Visual Studio the WDK to be installed.

I followed this article form MSDN: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk

and still I don't have the templates for drivers development.

Things I did in order to fix it (Which did not work):

1. Add features to my VS17 like mention in the article above.
2. Repair VS17.
3. Install VS19 like mention in the article and add the needed features.
4. Repair VS19.

Nothing worked and I have no idea what to do.

I would like to get some help about it..

Comment: Install Windows SDK 18362 then VS2019 then WDK 18362. Follow the exact order.

Comment: First to uninstall my current VS19 installation?

Comment: @pablo - VS2017 and VS2019 can exist on the same system.   Wouldn't it be easier to just install both VS2017 and VS2019 and install whatever version of the Windows WDK you need once?

Comment: Currently I have both. I did not uninstall VS17 before installing VS19. All I'm asking is what to do in order to have WDK available for me in VS19 or VS17 (does not matter).